Problem for Fitting data with a lognormal function via Maximum Likelihood Estimation for Fragility Curves
I am working with a dataset where I want to estimate the parameters of a lognormal distribution using Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE). The data represents observed probabilities of events (like slight, heavily, and collapsed damages) occurring at different levels of a predictor variable, e.g. peak ground acceleration (PGA).
I’ve written a script to fit a lognormal cumulative distribution function (CDF) to the observed data using MLE, but I am encountering optimization issues. Specifically:

For one damage level, the optimization terminates with unrealistic parameter estimates and doesn’t converge properly.
For another damage level, the results are logical, and the optimization is successful.
For the third level, the optimization stops because the maximum number of iterations or function evaluations is exceeded, and the parameter estimates are extremely high or unrealistic.

The output suggests that the optimization algorithm is struggling, possibly due to poor initial parameter guesses, numerical instability, or issues with how the likelihood function is defined.
How can I properly fit a lognormal distribution to my data using MLE in a way that avoids these issues? Are there standard methods or built-in functions in Python that can help streamline this process?
My Input data to use for deriving Fragility curve is imaged as you can see below:

The problem from my script occurred when I run it; I have tried to three fragility curves (slight, heavily and collapsed). The mean and standard deviation values for slight and collapsed are illogical.
print(res_slight)
 final_simplex: (array([[1., 1.],
 [1., 1.],
 [1., 1.]]), array([inf, inf, inf]))
 fun: inf
 message: 'Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.'
 nfev: 403
 nit: 101
 status: 1
 success: False
 x: array([1., 1.])

print(res_heavily)
 final_simplex: (array([[0.63531661, 0.88823413],
 [0.6353701 , 0.88832485],
 [0.63533704, 0.88817963]]), array([203.91066709, 203.91066948, 203.91068102]))
 fun: 203.91066708806784
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
 nfev: 60
 nit: 32
 status: 0
 success: True
 x: array([0.63531661, 0.88823413])

print(res_collapsed)
 final_simplex: (array([[8.67945396e+20, 3.53694860e+01],
 [7.84728875e+20, 3.53008691e+01],
 [7.54836798e+20, 3.52584876e+01]]), array([183.64705108, 183.64785074, 183.6479341 ]))
 fun: 183.64705108393747
 message: 'Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.'
 nfev: 1823
 nit: 1000
 status: 2
 success: False
 x: array([8.67945396e+20, 3.53694860e+01])

This is why my fragility curves like the attached figure:

My code to derive fragility curves is:
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize, stats


PGA_Values = np.array([0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.20, 0.22, 0.24, 0.26, 0.28, 0.30, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.40,
               0.42, 0.44, 0.46, 0.48, 0.50, 0.52, 0.54, 0.56, 0.58, 0.60, 0.62, 0.64, 0.66, 0.68, 0.70,
               0.72])

im_log = np.log(PGA_Values)

#Slight Damage Data Results
slight_damage_analyses = np.array([46, 11, 18, 54, 30, 1482, 17, 73, 1082, 341, 798, 9509, 4226, 107, 7, 1,1,
                               3, 11, 103, 9, 27, 21, 22, 40, 22, 90, 98, 1006, 402, 1]) 

slight_damage_collapses = np.array([29, 5, 12, 33, 18, 1314, 10, 47, 656, 217, 611, 6751, 2734, 69, 2, 0, 0,
                                0, 5, 49, 5, 0, 7, 8, 13, 3, 55, 67, 342, 260, 1])

#Heavily  Damage Data Results
heavily_damage_analyses = np.array([46, 11, 18, 54, 30, 1482, 17, 73, 1082, 341, 798, 9509, 4226, 107, 7, 1,1,
                               3, 11, 103, 9, 27, 21, 22, 40, 22, 90, 98, 1006, 402, 1]) 

heavily_damage_collapses = np.array([15, 6, 3, 18, 12, 150, 5, 18, 342, 83, 160, 2244, 1107, 27, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                4, 49, 3, 6, 10, 12, 17, 6, 34, 27, 597, 114, 0])

#Collapsed Data Results
collapsed_damage_analyses = np.array([46, 11, 18, 54, 30, 1482, 17, 73, 1082, 341, 798, 9509, 4226, 107, 7, 1,1,
                               3, 11, 103, 9, 27, 21, 22, 40, 22, 90, 98, 1006, 402, 1]) 

collapsed_damage_collapses = np.array([2, 0, 3, 3, 0, 18, 2, 8, 84, 41, 27, 514, 385, 11, 4, 1, 0, 2, 2, 5, 1,
                                21, 4, 2, 10, 13, 1, 4, 67, 28, 0])



def neg_log_likelihood_sum(params, im_l, no_a, no_c):
    sigma, beta = params
    theoretical_fragility_function = stats.norm(np.log(sigma), beta).cdf(im_l)
    likelihood = stats.binom.pmf(no_c, no_a, theoretical_fragility_function)
    log_likelihood = np.log(likelihood)
    log_likelihood_sum = np.sum(log_likelihood + 1e+10)

    print(FORMAT_STRING.format(sigma, beta, log_likelihood_sum))
    return -log_likelihood_sum



# Slight Damage Data fitting using MLE
neg_log_likelihood_sum_partial_slight = partial(neg_log_likelihood_sum, im_l=np.log(PGA_Values), no_a=slight_damage_analyses, no_c=slight_damage_collapses)
res_slight = optimize.minimize(neg_log_likelihood_sum_partial_slight, (1, 1), method="Nelder-Mead")

# Heavily Damage Data fitting using MLE
neg_log_likelihood_sum_partial_heavily = partial(neg_log_likelihood_sum, im_l=np.log(PGA_Values), no_a=heavily_damage_analyses, no_c=heavily_damage_collapses)
res_heavily = optimize.minimize(neg_log_likelihood_sum_partial_heavily, (1, 1), method="Nelder-Mead")

# Collapsed Data fitting using MLE
neg_log_likelihood_sum_partial_collapsed = partial(neg_log_likelihood_sum, im_l=np.log(PGA_Values), no_a=collapsed_damage_analyses, no_c=collapsed_damage_collapses)
res_collapsed = optimize.minimize(neg_log_likelihood_sum_partial_collapsed, (1, 1), method="Nelder-Mead")


# Plotting Fragility Curves 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 100)

# Slight Damage 
y_slight = stats.norm(np.log(res_slight.x[0]), res_slight.x[1]).cdf(np.log(x))
plt.plot(x, y_slight, label='Slight Damage')

# Heavily Damage 
y_heavily = stats.norm(np.log(res_heavily.x[0]), res_heavily.x[1]).cdf(np.log(x))
plt.plot(x, y_heavily, label='Heavily Damage')

# Collapsed 
y_collapsed = stats.norm(np.log(res_collapsed.x[0]), res_collapsed.x[1]).cdf(np.log(x))
plt.plot(x, y_collapsed, label='Collapsed')

plt.scatter(PGA_Values, slight_damage_collapses / slight_damage_analyses, color='blue', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(PGA_Values, heavily_damage_collapses / heavily_damage_analyses, color='orange', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(PGA_Values, collapsed_damage_collapses / collapsed_damage_analyses, color='r', alpha=0.5)


Can you try to rephrase your question with less domain-specific jargon? "Fragility curve" seems to be a concept of civil engineering, but many more people might be able to help if you use standard statistical terminology. If you have observations of a lognormally distributed random variable and you want to perform MLE to estimate the parameters, that should be easy - just pass the data into scipy.stats.lognorm.fit, possibly with floc or fscale to fix the location and/or scale. If you have something else, please take some more time to describe your problem before jumping into code.

@MattHaberland, i’ve just editted my question that can help understand it easily. Thank you!

Ok, stats.lognorm.fit is for fitting a distribution to raw observations, not estimates of a CDF. If you have the observations or want to try converting your CDF estimates to equivalent observations (for which the CDF estimate is the empirical CDF), we can go that route. But it would help to simplify the question to be about just one of these CDFs and to include the data rather than a screenshot.
